# No buffer available on Debian-Machine

Tags: debian, socket, buffer

I'm running a LAMP-Stack on a debian machine for a while now.
I configured it the way I'm used to, which never produced weird network or memory issues.

On random days at random time I'm getting a bunch of mails from monit.d about connection errors on mysql, exim, ssh and limit breaking cpu usage. The monit-log is showing a lot of "no buffer available".

There is no event I'm aware of, which could triggers this plus it's happening on random days and time.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Programs:

- apache2
- php7-fpm
- mysqld
- monit.d
- munin

CPU-Load load is normally under 5% and RAM usage under 50%.
Server is used for an internal cloud with 5-10 active users during the day.

Part of monit.d log:

```
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : Connection failed -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : Cannot open a connection to the mailserver '127.0.0.1:25' -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : Sendmail: No mail servers are available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : Alert handler failed, retry scheduled for next cycle
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : 'localhost' cpu system usage of 75.1% matches resource limit [cpu system usage>30.0%]
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : 'localhost' loadavg(5min) of 3.1 matches resource limit [loadavg(5min)>2.0]
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : Connection failed -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : socket_create: Could not create socket -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : 'apache2' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:80] via TCP
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : Connection failed -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : socket_create: Could not create socket -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] error    : 'mysql' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[127.0.0.1:3306] via TCP
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] info     : 'mysql' trying to restart
[CET Jan 27 22:57:38] info     : 'mysql' stop: /etc/init.d/mysql
[CET Jan 27 22:57:41] info     : 'mysql' start: /etc/init.d/mysql
[CET Jan 27 22:57:46] error    : Connection failed -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:46] error    : socket_create: Could not create socket -- No buffer space available
[CET Jan 27 22:57:46] error    : 'exim4' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:25] via TCP
[CET Jan 27 22:57:46] info     : 'exim4' trying to restart
[CET Jan 27 22:57:46] info     : 'exim4' stop: /etc/init.d/exim4
[CET Jan 27 22:57:46] info     : 'exim4' start: /etc/init.d/exim4
```